# Get highest sum value from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Here is my code:

```
$query1 = "select user, sum(column) as total1 from table1 GROUP BY user";
$result = mysql_query(query1);
$row_query1 = mysql_fech_assoc($result);

do{
    $user = $row_query1['user'];
    $query2 = "select names, sum(column1) as total2 from table2 WHERE names ='$user' GROUP BY names";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $row_query2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $sum = $row_query1['total1'] + $row_query2['total1'];
    <tr> <?php echo $sum; ?></tr>
}while($row_query1 = mysql_fech_assoc($result));
```

I need to get the highest value of $sum from this loop. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it working? check this inside loop - "<tr> <?php echo $sum; ?></tr>"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.. take a temporary variable($temp) which can have check upon the sum variable($sum).

```
     $query1 = "select user, sum(column) as total1 from table1 GROUP BY user";
     $result = mysql_query(query1);
     $row_query1 = mysql_fech_assoc($result);
     $temp = 0;

    do{

    $user = $row_query1['user'];

    $query2 = "select names, sum(column1) as total2 from table2 WHERE names ='$user' GROUP BY names";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $row_query2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

    $sum = $row_query1['total1'] + $row_query2['total1'];

    if($temp < $sum)
    $temp = sum;

    echo "<tr>$sum</tr>";

   }while($row_query1 = mysql_fech_assoc($result));
   echo "maximum sum :".$temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice doing a JOIN instead of performing the sub queries yourself:

```
select user, sum(column) + sum(column1) as total
from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON names = user
GROUP BY user
```

The rest should be straightforward in code.